# Upper bound for modulus of a complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

Let $\gamma$ be a close piecewise smooth contour consisting of the three straight lines from $1$ to $2$, from $2$ to $1+i$ and from $1+i$ to $1$.

I have to show that
$$\left|\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{\overline z +i}\,dz\right|\leq 2+\sqrt{2}$$

I know that I can use the estimation lemma to bound
$$\left|\frac{1}{\overline z +i}\right|\leq M$$ and I think that must be $M=1$, because $\lvert\gamma\rvert=2+\sqrt2$, but I can't find a suitable upper bound. Any hint?

Maybe $$\left|\frac{1}{\overline z +i}\right|= \frac{1}{\lvert\overline z +i\rvert}\leq\frac{1}{\lvert\overline z\rvert - \lvert i\rvert}=\frac{1}{\lvert z\rvert - 1}$$
but this does not give me any further information since $1\leq\lvert z\rvert\leq 2$

Comment: Use $|A| = |\bar A|$.

Comment: @aschepler do you mean something like $\left|\overline{\frac{1}{\overline z +  i}}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{z-  i}\right|$...but I don't see any boundary again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the points where $\left|\frac1{\overline z+i}\right|\le1$:
$$|\overline z+i|\le1\iff\overline z\text{ is in unit circle centred on }-i$$
$$\iff z\text{ is in unit circle centred on }i$$
Since all parts of the curve lie on or outside the unit circle centred on $i$, $\left|\frac1{\overline z+i}\right|\le1$ on all of $\gamma$ and we get the desired result.

Comment: Very intuitive way, thanks!

Comment: @GiacomoGatti Please upvote and accept my answer :)